# robocopy command to move file based on created date

Tags: batch-file, robocopy

I have files in a folder 'FILEPATH', each file has different created date and modified date(modified date is less than created date).
I want to delete the files with created date greater than 10days. I used below command but it works on modified date.

```
ROBOCOPY %FILEPATH% %DUMPFOLDER% /move /minage:10

del %DUMPFOLDER% /q
```

On some forums its written that minage refers to created date but it's referring to modified date while executing. Am I doing something wrong here? Or is there any other alternate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, there's no easy way to do this.  The only commands of which I'm aware that can deal with file *creation* dates are `dir /t:c` and `wmic datafile`.  There could be others, but there are none that simplify performing date math as `forfiles` or `robocopy` do.

Since date math in batch is cumbersome anyway, in this situation it makes sense to borrow from another runtime environment -- PowerShell, for example, or VBScript or JScript.  The Windows Scripting Host [`FileSystemObject`'s `File` Object](http://ss64.com/vb/filesystemobject.html) has properties for `DateCreated`, `DateLastAccessed`, and `DateModified`.  With JScript, getting a file's age based on its `DateCreated` property is simply a matter of JavaScript `Date()` arithmetic.

Here, salt this `.bat` script to taste:

```js
@if (@CodeSection == @Batch) @then

@echo off
setlocal

set "FILEPATH=c:\path\to\whatever"
set "age=10"

for %%I in ("%FILEPATH%\*") do (
    call :getAge result "%%~fI"
    setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
    if !result! gtr %age% (
        echo %%~nxI created !result! days ago and should be deleted
        rem del "%%~fI"
    ) else (
        echo %%~nxI is new ^(created !result! days ago^)
    )
    endlocal
)

goto :EOF

:getAge <return_var> <filename>
for /f "delims=" %%I in ('cscript /nologo /e:Jscript "%~f0" "%~2"') do set "%~1=%%I"
goto :EOF

@end

// JScript portion

var fso = WSH.CreateObject('scripting.filesystemobject'),
    created = fso.GetFile(WSH.Arguments(0)).DateCreated,
    age = new Date() - created;

WSH.Echo(Math.floor(age / 1000 / 60 / 60 / 24));
```

If you want something simpler, you could employ `wmic datafile` and get the first 8 digits of `get creationdate` [like this cat does](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22524798/1683264), but his solution doesn't take into account time of day.  Such a method might inappropriately delete files that are 9 days, 23 hours old.  Then there's also the problem of calculating days across new months.  The JScript method above tests file age based on the current moment, rather than based on midnight; and will handle spanning months, years, and leap years with no conscious effort.

Comment: my restriction is to use batch command only. I'm using xcopy to copy files from source folder to filepath. Is there a way I could modify date modified while or after copying the file .    XCOPY %FILE_PATH% %SOURCE%  and if i can get the date modified same as date created I could simply use above robocopy.

Comment: @Aman Seems like an unnecessary restriction to me. What happens if you try to run the script as it is, changing only the `set "FILEPATH=path"` line?  To answer your question, you could invoke a PowerShell command to set the modified timestamp equal to the created timestamp on every file, but it'd be much slower than the solution I have above.  And ultimately, if you're going to be invoking a different runtime anyway, there's little practical difference between `cscript.exe` and `powershell.exe`, other than `cscript` is faster.